# Vigenère cipher

Tags: riddle, cipher, letters

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ = 0-25

List of keys starting in order you need to use them.

- Comic
- Bacon
- Key

Cipher: QWUA BT UICL

Video on how to use the [Vigenère cipher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zASwVoshiM)

Hint:

> This is triple coded, meaning you will get a total of thee ciphers before you get your final answer (make sure to use all the keys in order.)

Comment: Are you suggesting to do a brute force on the cipher? Is there any other encryption used apart from Vigenere ? :-/

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE!  Have a look at [Code Puzzles - What (Not) To Do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) for some helpful tips on how to make cipher questions into better quality puzzles.

Comment: Just an FYI - it doesn't matter what order you apply Vigenere keys - each letter's translation is simply the sum of all translations for that index in the string. The three keys you presented add up to a combined key of NSMGTBYSUZHMYAN.

Answer (score 4):

Either this puzzle is misleading, or (possibly) you've done something wrong.

> You seem to have the expectation that people here are unfamiliar with  Vigenère ciphers, so the first line of your posting ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ = 0-25") seems like a well-intentioned, though unnecessary, bit of information—it's a description of part of the operation of the cipher, so shouldn't be needed.  If we ignore it as such, and apply the given keys in order as suggested, we get:
>
>  $\begin{array}{lll}\bf{Applying\ Vigenere\ to}&\bf{With\ the\ key}&\bf{Yields...}\\\hline\text{QWUA BT UICL}&\text{COMIC}&\text{OIIS ZR GWUJ}\\\hline\text{OIIS ZR GWUJ}&\text{BACON}&\text{NIGE MQ GUGW}\\\hline\text{NIGE MQ GUGW}&\text{KEY}&\text{DEIU IS WQIM}\\\hline\end{array}$
>  which is clearly a nonsensical result.
>
>  That first line is the only bit of information that seems out of place and thus a possible hint to what's missing, but if that's the intention, it's entirely unclear how we're supposed to apply it.  Translating the provided letters to numbers at any point along the way gives us a bunch of numbers that have no particular meaning.

Is there something missing from the puzzle?